# What's the most elegant way to use stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I'm re-writing the inline SQL in my repository class to use stored procedures instead (security requirement). After using Fluent NHibernate and Linq2Sql in the past I'm finding it to be extremely unwieldy and inelegant.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm not looking for an ORM solution that works with stored procs. I just want some advice on a nice way to write the code below.

Are there any strategies for making this sort of code as elegant as possible?

```
        string commandText = "dbo.Save";

        using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connString.ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = sql.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("identity", item.Identity);
            idParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("name", item.Name);
            nameParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            SqlParameter descParam = new SqlParameter("desc", item.Description);
            descParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            SqlParameter titleParam = new SqlParameter("title", item.)
            descParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            //SNIP More parameters

            cmd.Parameters.Add(idParam);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(descParam);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(titleParam);
            //SNIP etc

            sql.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //Get out parameters
        }

        return item;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within our internal applications we generally use the SqlHelper class which can be found at the following link (download and description): http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=f63d1f0a-9877-4a7b-88ec-0426b48df275&displaylang=en

Essentially the SqlHelper class takes away some of the need to declare connection objects, commands etc and allows you to call methods to return objects such as DataSet

You might then use SqlHelper as such:

```
public static int UpdateItem(int parameter1, int parameter2, string parameter3)
    {
        SqlParameter[] arParam = new SqlParameter[3];
        arParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@Parameter1", lotId);
        arParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@Parameter2", saleId);
        arParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@Parameter3", lotNumber);


        return int.Parse(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spName", arParam).ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Rumor has it that the EntLib will be updated for .NET 3.5 to support LINQ.

Comment: SqlHelper will also cache the parameters in _some_ of the overloads, which will save trips to the db.  In the above, .NET will round trip to the db to discover the datatype for @Parameter1,etc. Be sure to read up on it's usage.

Answer (score 6):

Grab a copy of [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx).  It is a nice wrapper around ADO.  For example:

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;

Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(DatabaseType.MyDatabase.ToString());

using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.MyStoredProc")) {
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "identity", DbType.Int32, item.Identity);
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "name", DbType.String, item.Name);
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "desc", DbType.String, item.Description);
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "title", DbType.String, item.Title);

    db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
} // using dbCommand
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use some variation of the following example, depending on the environment of course:

**My basic helper methods that I call throughout my code**

```
public static SqlCommand CreateStoredProcCmd(string name, SqlConnection con)
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(name, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    return cmd;
}

public static void AddParams(this SqlCommand cmdObject, Params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
  foreach(SqlParameter param in parameters)
  {
    cmdObject.Parameters.add(param);
  }
}

/* Any overloaded methods to create params receiving my param definitions 
in any manner that the usual new SqlParameter() constructor doesn't handle */
public static SqlParameter CreateSqlParam(string ParamName,
                                          SqlDbType ParamType,
                                          object value)
{
    return CreateSqlParam(ParamName, ParamType, ParameterDirection.Input, value);
}

public static SqlParameter CreateSqlParam(string ParamName, 
                                          SqlDbType ParamType, 
                                          ParameterDirection ParamDir)
{
    return CreateSqlParam(ParamName, ParamType, ParamDir, null;
}                          

public static SqlParameter CreateSqlParam(string ParamName, 
                                          SqlDbType ParamType, 
                                          ParameterDirection ParamDir,
                                          object value)
{
    var parm = new SqlParameter(ParamName, ParamType);
    parm.Direction = ParamDir;
    parm.Value = value;
    return parm;
}
```

**Now here's how I set up my stored procs and add all my parameters elegantly**

```
public static string DoStuff()
{
    using (var oCon = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
    {
        oCon.Open();
        var oCmd = CreateStoredProcCmd("sp_Name", oCon).AddParams(
            CreateSqlParam("Param1", SqlDBType.Int, 3),
            CreateSqlParam("Param2", SqlDBType.VarChar, "Hello World"),
            CreateSqlParam("Param3", SqlDBType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Output)
        );
        oCmd.Prepare();
        oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        object outVal = oCmd.Parameters["Param3"];
        return null != outVal ? outVal.ToString() : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SubSonic](http://irene-eux.com/zcvisitor/fce1e821-457f-11ed-b8aa-0a56fd9e5fbf/72092e88-2c53-401c-b988-51ef43ce1034?campaignid=599ad610-1c7e-11ed-940e-0a918cbcbb97) as an ORM layer between your class and the stored procedures. Here's a basic [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20150713072104/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/scottkuhl/archive/2006/12/08/100700.aspx). Phil Haack has a good [article](https://haacked.com/archive/2007/05/29/strongly-typed-stored-procedures-using-subsonic.aspx/) on it as well.

There's some good info in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687762/which-orm-is-the-best-when-using-stored-procedures).

EDIT: Since you've updated your question to indicate you don't want to use an ORM, SubSonic is not for you. However, I'll leave the answer here for other folks who use stored procs. :) You should also take a look at if there's even a possibility you can use it.

Comment: Thanks I'd not seen that, however I'm advised not to use 3rd party tech outside of the existing tooling because it needs to be approved by the client and that takes ages.

Comment: So don't tell them it's "third party tech." You should also update your question with this info.

Comment: Can't really get away with that. I'll look at it to see what the implication is, I'll store it in the bank for later use if not.

Answer (score 2):

You could halve the linecount by deriving your own InputSqlParameter from SqlParameter and setting the direction to Input in the constructor.

That would let you write

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new InputSqlParameter("title", item.title));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new InputSqlParameter("property", item.property));
```

This shows a pattern, and lets you setup a list of parameter names and item fields and do the parameter adding in a **for** loop.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the Microsoft Application Blocks SqlHelper object.

For a statement like you have listed above, I can do the following.

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(_connectionString, "MyProcName", 1, "NameValue", "Description", "Title");
```

Basically SQL Helper takes a few parameters.

1. The Connection String to connect to the db
2. The name of the stored procedure
3. An array of parameter values, in the order in which they appear in the Stored Procedure.

There is a VERY slight performance drawback with this method over explicitly creating each parameter, but the time savings usually outbalances it since it is so small.

Comment: Is there really a performance drawback? Doesn't the compiler take care of that?

Comment: I actually just got done running a bunch of tests. with a 5 parameter stored procedure there is a 7% difference when issuing between 1 and 1000 statements.  After 1000 it drops a bit to about 4% or so.  Once I hit about 20000 inserts there was no difference.

It appears linked to caching.

Comment: But really given the times involved, the performance differenct is hardly something you would notice a difference of .0003 seconds for single entries.

Answer (score 2):

To make the code a little less verbose i've always added parameters using

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", item.Name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", item.Title);
// and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

Input is the default direction and you can shorten the parameter adding and probably want to declare the SqlDBTypes as well...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("identity", SqlDBType.???).Value = item.Identity;
cmd.Parameters.Add("desc", SqlDbType.???, ?size?).Value = item.Description;
cmd.Parameters.Add("title", SqlDBType.???, ?size?).Value = item.Title;

//Output params generally don't need a value so...
cmd.Parameters.Add("someOut", SqlDBType.???).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep each parameter for a given stored procedure in a "data class."  Use annotations to specify things like "in" or "out" sproc parameters.

Then you can load up the class from client code, then use reflection to build all the parameters for the sproc, execute the sproc, and load the output parameters back into the data class.

Slightly more clean: Have one class for inputs and another for outputs (even if some are in/out).  That way it's clear (to client code) which parameters need to be filled on the way in and which get returned.  Also this obviates the need for those annotations.

Comment: Interesting... I'll have a play with that

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[Save]";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(
        "Identity", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = item.Identity });

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(
        "Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50) { Value = item.Name });

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(
        "Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Value = item.Title });

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Here is how it could look like with **Ent Lib**:

```
// Note, that you don't need to specify connection string here,
// it will be automatically taken from a configuration file
var db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

using (var cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("[dbo].[Save]"))
{
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "Identity", DbType.Int32, item.Identity);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "Name", DbType.String, item.Name);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "Title", DbType.String, item.Title);
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
}
```

You can also use SqlHelper method from Enterprise Library to simplify this syntax.

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectinString,
     CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[dbo].[Save]", new SqlParameter[]
         {
             new SqlParameter("Identity", item.Identity),
             new SqlParameter("Name", item.Name),
             new SqlParameter("Title", item.Title)
         });
```

Comment: Don't need to try finally if using "using" it calls dispose automatically which itself calls close