# what is subsonic?

Tags: subsonic

I'm lost here, can someone explain to me what subsonic is?

is it a code generator type tool?

Comment: subsonic is  a sort of big baloon which someone call that ORM. who can tell that is ORM after EF, Hybernate and tons of ORM in software world. question hidden by your answer. it is a code generator type tool. thats all. and codes produced by subsonic is really weak.

Answer (score 5):

"[SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) is A Super High-fidelity Batman Utility Belt that works up your Data Access (using Linq in 3.0), throws in some much-needed utility functions, and generally speeds along your dev cycle."

Depending on how you use it, it does involve code generation (t4 templates used to create classes that represent your database objects).

Answer (score 2):

[This website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsonic_(software)), Wikipedia, tells me its an ORM (Object-Relational Mapper)

Answer (score 0):

As it's creator Rob Conery says, it's the Swiss Army Knife of ORMS.

Here are some other questions where you can find out about SubSonic:

[What ORM is the best when using stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687762/which-orm-is-the-best-when-using-stored-procedures/687899#687899)

[Best free ORM to use with .Net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206197/best-free-orm-tools-to-use-with-net-2-0-3-5/206284#206284)

If you haven't go to [SubSonic's site](http://www.subsonicproject.com) and watch some of the tutorials.  You find that it is easy to become in under 30 minutes.